# isDisplayed generic method for selenium

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

i would like to create a generic method for isDisplayed for selenium web driver class which will accept 3 params 1) driver 2) locatorType 3) locator value
so  i want to come up with one generic method call which will address isDislayed method for **id** , **name** or **classname** or **xpath**.
pls let me know how to solv this prb ?

**thought**: *if i use switch statement in java i can return the boolean value like true or not. but its telling return cannot be reach for switch*

code sample : http://chopapp.com/#5rrqt63f

Comment: Laxmi you will get more help around here if you show us what you have already tried instead of asking us to do it for you.

Answer (score 0):

u can try like below:

```
public boolean  method(WebDriver driver,  By locatortype){

        //do what u want
        boolean result = driver.findElement(locatortype).isDisplayed(); 
        return result;          
}
```

now u can use this method like below:

```
By locatortype = By.cssSelector("selector");
```

or

```
By locatortype = By.id("id");
```

or

```
By locatortype = By.xpath("xpath");
```

and call the method like below:

```
method(driver,locatortype);
```

Comment: if u dont want boolean method, than remove boolean, make it void and remove the return type.

Comment: klaxmi361@gmail.com. let me know your id. will share the code